# Does spring native already support all components of spring?

Tags: graalvm, spring-native

Does spring native already support all components of spring? Or are there any other unsupported components？
Is there a roadmap for spring native?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Josh Long the Spring Developer Advocate has stated that it's due in late 2022

https://www.infoq.com/articles/native-java-spring-boot/?itm_source=infoq&itm_campaign=user_page&itm_medium=link

Answer (score 0):

Updated for anybody who finds this, this is now supported in Spring Boot 3.0 for all main spring libraries. Documentation available https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/native-image.html